# How to get a list of the entries of Windows control panel using Lua

Tags: windows, lua

How can we get a list of the entries of Windows control panel using Lua and how can we remove any particular program in a control panel from a Lua script.

We can invoke the control panel from a Lua script as below:

```
os.execute("control appwiz.cpl")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you read a value from the windows registry? You can check the `HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall` key for your programs uninstall strings, then invoke `Msiexec /uninstall yourprogram.exe`.

Comment: Which Key are you talking about. I can access the Registry Key from the LUA and can see the executable in the path HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall. Please explain in more detail

Comment: Each entry under this key correspond to a program that is installed into the system. Each one of them has an `UninstallString` string value, which contains the application's specific uninstall command.  If you copy that command and paste into "Run" and execute it, you can see it invokes the application uninstaller. If you can manage to execute it from Lua, you can uninstall applications this way.